# Use session to echo result on different page

Tags: php, session

First of all. I am a newbie on PHP . so please understand.
I have tried using session to echo the result of createmessage.php back into index.php

Createmessage.php

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_convo(t_datetime,t_subject, t_message, t_category, t_ipaddress, t_password) VALUES('$date','$subject','$message','$category','$ipaddress','$password')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        $msg = "<div class='col-sm-12'><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert' style='text-align:center;'>Successfull Sent</div></div>";
        $_SESSION['answer'] = $msg; 

        header('Location: index.php');
```

index.php

```
<?php if( !isset($_SESSION['answer'])) {$array = $_SESSION['answer']; echo $array; } ?>
```

Please kindly help me how to fix this session.

Comment: I need to "echo "<div class='col-sm-12'><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert' style='text-align:center;'>Successfull Sent</div></div>";" back to index page without messing its html.

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn how to use AJAX, so you can send to the PHP script without reloading the current page.

Comment: Which means you first have to learn Javascript.

Comment: I think I just need to session the result on createmessage.php then header it back to index.php . i just dont know how to save it into session. please help. sorry im really a newbie on php.

Comment: Yes, you can use session for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the other way around. Instead of

```
if (!isset ...
```

You need to do

```
if (isset ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['color'] = 'green';
?>
```

Have a look at [PHP SESSIONS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

And here is a simple example [Simple Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm)